# How do I get the <p> tag parent class name using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get the `<p>` tag's parent class name?

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
```

How can I obtain this?

Comment: What is it you're *actually* trying to do? Perhaps there is a different approach. Code please.

Answer (score 6):

Some find that using css and the nokogiri `parent` method are easier to read/maintain than xpath:

```
html = %q{
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
}

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.css('p').each do |p|
    puts p.parent.attr('class')
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Use an XPath like `//p/..` or `//*[p]` (the parent of any "p" element at any depth).

```ruby
str =<<__HERE__
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
__HERE__

html = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
p_parents = html.xpath('//p/..') # => NodeSet containing the "<div>" element.
p_parents.each do |node|
  puts node.attr('class') # => "entry-content"
end
```

Comment: It works but not says div's class name, only "div". There is any way to know the class name? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, using .value it gives div id and class! Thank you again!

Comment: @HugoSousa: try reading the "class" attribute of the node, e.g. `node.attr('class') # => "entry-content"`.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but that is IMHO better expressed as `//*[p]`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `#at_css`,instead of `css`.

```
require 'nokogiri'

str =<<__HERE__
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
__HERE__

html = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
p_parent = html.at_css('p').parent
p_parent.name # => "div"
p_parent['class'] # => "entry-content"
```

Comment: Note that "at_css" returns only a single element whereas "css" returns a NodeSet.

Comment: @maerics yes,I know that. As we are here concentrating on the parent element,so I think `#at_css` will be good to use.

Comment: `at` or `at_css` is only safe if there is only one `<p>` tag in the document, or the OP only wants the parent of the *first* `<p>`. If there are multiple `<p>` tags, `at` or `at_css` will do the wrong thing.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes you are right exactly..But from the post of OP,that was not mentioned..So I gave this `at` or `at_css` example...

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use-case for XPath. Here's how I'd go about it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>Some text...</p>
</div>
EOT

puts doc.at('//p/..')['class']
```

Which outputs: `entry-content`.

If you could have multiple `<p>` tags and need to access the class of their parents, use:

```
puts doc.search('//p/..').map{ |n| n['class'] }
```

Which again outputs: `entry-content`.

In either case, using the `[]` notation is a shortcut for retrieving the value associated with a parameter of a tag.

And, just as we'd see `..` at the *nix command-line when listing directories, `..` means the parent element.

Nokogiri supports using CSS selectors to navigate through a document, but CSS didn't support a "parent" accessor for a long time. CSS 4 does have a way to get there but Nokogiri v1.6.0 doesn't seem to support it yet. For example, we should be able to use a selector like `$* > p` but it doesn't work:

```
doc.at('$* > p')
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '$' after ''

doc.at('* > p')
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff7c099f528 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff7c099f2e4 "Some text...">]>
```

The `$` is a marker in CSS that says that particular part of the selector is what we're interested in. See "[Determining the Subject of a Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#subject)" for more information. Once Nokogiri supports "subjects", we can streamline our CSS selectors and their accompanying Ruby code because we won't need to use `parent` methods to set up to the parent nodes. Until then, well, we still have the old works around of using `parent`.